# How do I send an email and close the current inspector from within an Outlook form region?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook 2010 AdjoiningFormRegion that contains a single button.  The idea is that a user composes an email then clicks my send button instead of the usual outlook send button.  My send button will communicate some info to a web service then send the email as usual and close the inspector window? Is this even possible?  It would be great to hook into a send event but I've had no luck figuring this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Send method of the MailItem class will send the email and close the window just as clicking the Send button does.

```csharp
(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem).Send()
```